# Error: File format is not supported in file

Tags: python

I made a simple sphere in blender, since Ursina doesn't support UV maps. When I tried launching the game, I got this:

````
*found blend file: C:\Users\nadja\OneDrive\Dokumenty\GitHub\pratformjump\assets\skymodel.blend*

*blender_version: 3.0*

*converting .blend file to .obj: C:\Users\nadja\OneDrive\Dokumenty\GitHub\pratformjump\assets\skymodel.blend --> C:\Users\nadja\OneDrive\Dokumenty\GitHub\pratformjump\models_compressed\skymodel.obj using: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\blender.exe*

*Blender 3.0.0 (hash f1cca3055776 built 2021-12-03 00:44:02)*

*Read prefs: C:\Users\nadja\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.0\config\userpref.blend*

*Read blend: C:\Users\nadja\OneDrive\Dokumenty\GitHub\pratformjump\assets\skymodel.blend*

*Error: File format is not supported in file 'C:\Users\nadja\OneDrive\Dokumenty\GitHub\pratformjump\models_compressed\skymodel.obj'*

```
````

Comment: Hello ! The error comes from your game engine or from Blender ?

Comment: @Gorgious game engine

Comment: @Gorgious also its Ursina i forgot to mention